# Make each pixel value display a different color in a shapefile

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, image-segmentation

[TLDR]
I am working on converting a segmentation model output into a shapefile that can be added as a layer on a map. I was hoping to find how to make each pixel value have a different color instead of all black?

I am relatively new to all of this. So far, I've been able to generate the shapefile using the script below:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
raster = gdal.Open(r'test.tif')
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()

proj = raster.GetProjection()
shp_proj = osr.SpatialReference()
shp_proj.ImportFromWkt(proj)

output_file = 'test.shp'
call_drive = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
create_shp = call_drive.CreateDataSource(output_file)

shp_layer = create_shp.CreateLayer('LandCover', srs = shp_proj)
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn(str('ID'), ogr.OFTInteger)
shp_layer.CreateField(new_field)

gdal.Polygonize(band, None, shp_layer, 0, [], callback=None)
create_shp.Destroy()
raster = None
```

And it looks like this on QGIS:
[image]

What the original TIFF looks like
[image]

Are there any ways we can generate the shapefile so that each pixel values have different colors? eg

- 0 => transparent
- 1 => blue
- 2 => green etc.

Comment: A shapefile doesn't come with colors. You need to style it, for example in QGIS: qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html . The style is saved in the map document.

Comment: I was able to do this in QGIS. But I'm exploring a way to do it in a script.

Comment: You cant. The style is not saved in the shapefile. It depends on which software you are using to display it. For example in QGIS you can save the style as a qml file, in ArcGIS a lyr

Comment: There are some software specific ways to store style into an attribute field. What might work with QGIS is to add an attribute that is named `OGR_STYLE` into the shapefile and save the style string as defined in https://gdal.org/user/ogr_feature_style.html. Or you can have a look at other formats that have more or less featured style support like KML https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/libkml.html or OpenJUMP JML https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/jml.html.

Comment: Thank you all for your clarifications! I decided to stick to exporting the style after formating on ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stick to exporting the style after formatting on QGIS. That is:

1. Importing the Shapefile created using the python script in the question to QGIS
2. Styling the Shapefile via the Properties->Symbology section.
3. Export the created layer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).